# How to apply scipy curve_fit to different magnitude data?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have two arrays: `x` ranges from 50 to 1000 while `y` ranges from 0 to 13.

I'm trying to fit them by the Gaussian function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


x = np.array([954.57747687, 845.47601272, 746.69873108, 657.48101282,
       577.09839969, 504.86539163, 440.13425151, 382.29381761,
       330.7683239 , 285.01622822, 244.52904868, 208.83020828,
       177.473888  , 150.04388862, 126.15250125, 105.4393871 ,
        87.57046634])

y = np.array([ 0.2,  0.5,  0.6,  1.4,  2.7,  4. ,  5. ,  6.2,  8.6, 10.3, 11.6,
       12.4, 12.7, 12.4,  7.6,  3. ,  0.8])

# Function to calculate the Gaussian with constants a, b, and c
def gaussian(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-np.power(x - b, 2)/(2*np.power(c, 2)))


pars, cov = curve_fit(f=gaussian, xdata=x, ydata=y)
print(pars) # [1. 1. 1.]

pars, cov = curve_fit(f=gaussian, xdata=x/100, ydata=y)
print(pars) # [12.38265077  2.49976014  1.18267892]


fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.scatter(y, x/100)
axs.plot(gaussian(x/100, *pars), x/100, linewidth=2, linestyle='--')
```

I have to scale the x data to make it work ... How to fit the data without manual scaling?

[image: example]

Comment: ...give proper initial guesses?

Comment: @mikuszefski Ha, thanks! I added `bounds=((-np.inf, 200, 50), (np.inf, 500, 250))`. Now, it works well

Comment: good to know. `bounds` or `p0`, both would work. I personally would prefer the latter. For automated fitting you could make an easy guess by using `max()` etc to get the amplitude FWHM and so on. Cheers.

Comment: As mikuszefski said, a nonlinear optimization algorithm can find local minima, so adequate initial parameters are required. The default initial parameter is (1, 1, ...).